# Running Maven on port 80

Tags: ip, maven, port-80

This question is a followup to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/288850/running-two-services-on-port-80).  I got Apache running on port 80 on one of my four IPs pretty easily.  Now I need to run Maven on port 80 on another IP.  [Running Maven on port 80](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/port80) is already difficult enough; I have no idea how to define a specific IP.  Any ideas on how to do this?  Perhaps ipchains or iptables would be the easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd guess that moving traffic from 80 to 8080 (or similar port) would be easiest:

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d <localip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination <localip>:8080`

Comment: Would --dport be 80, not 8080?

Comment: @Panthr you're correct, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I would set up [Apache to act as a reverse proxy](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) for Maven

Inside your virtualhost (presuming maven is bound to localhost port 8080):

```
ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```