# Is it possible to run two webservers on the same port on the same server? E.g., Apache and Lighttpd

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, configuration, virtualhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running two services on port 80](https://serverfault.com/questions/288850/running-two-services-on-port-80)

I have a QNAP TS-459 Pro II that comes with an Apache webserver which runs on port 80.

I'd also like to run a small [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com) app; also on port 80.

I'd like Apache to serve up `example.com` and `foo.example.com`, but I'd like Sinatra to serve up `bar.exapmle.com`.

Is it possible to have both webservers running on the same port but only answer based on specific domain binding?

Comment: Sure, both can use port 80 (on different interfaces.)

Comment: @Aaron don't even need two different physical interfaces. Subinterfaces are fine, as long as you have two IP's to run them on.

Comment: Yep - Virtual or physical, an interface is an interface.

Answer (score 2):

Only one app can have a particular port/IP combination open at a time , but you can approximate what you want by setting Apache up as a reverse proxy.

The highlights -

- Run Apache on port 80, and enable mod_proxy
- Do NOT turn on ProxyRequests (this is for forward proxying only)
- Run your other app on a different port and/or IP
- Use Apache virtual hosts and reverse proxy configuration to direct traffic to the appropriate site.

You can see these links for more info -

[ApacheTutor article](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)

[Apache mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, not unless you have two different public IP's on the server which each server can bind to. Each server then needs to explicitly listen on a specific IP/port combination and it will 'just work'.

The normal solution here if you only have access to a single IP address is to set up your Sinatra server on a different port (`localhost:808*` is popular), and then use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) in Apache to manage your Sinatra servers domain internally.

Comment: can you provide a mod_proxy example? If so, I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @macek: Personally we use nginx as the proxy and main webserver so I don't have one on hand. The Apache docs are really good though, you're looking to implement a reverse proxy: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html